# Arc Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for 'CSRGaia' declares the selector 'getUserEQ:'

Tags: objective-c, methods, bluetooth

I'm working on a react-native project that requires some native modules.  One of them is a Bluetooth module that allows me to access some CSRGaia methods.  Ultimately, I want to be able to read the eq values on the PS-key so that I can set my equalizer to the corresponding values.  I know almost nothing about Objective-C

Currently there is a method that looks like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setEQValues:(NSArray *)values callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    CSRPeripheral *connectedPeripheral = [CSRConnectionManager sharedInstance].connectedPeripheral;
    if( connectedPeripheral == nil )
    {
        callback(@[DISCONNECTED]);
        return;
    }
    [[CSRGaia sharedInstance] setEQValues:values];
}
```

This works with no issues.  However, when I tried to write my own

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getUserEQ: (NSArray *)values callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) 
{
    CSRPeripheral *connectedPeripheral = [CSRConnectionManager sharedInstance].connectedPeripheral;
    if( connectedPeripheral == nil) 
    {
        callback(@[DISCONNECTED]);
        return;
    }
    [[CSRGaia sharedInstance] getUserEQ: values];
}
```

I get the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'CSRGaia' declares the selector 'getUserEQ:'

I double checked the CSRGaia.m file to verify that both methods exist.

```
- (void)setEQValues:(NSArray *)values {
    NSMutableData *payload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for( NSNumber *value in values ) {
        uint8_t hex = [value unsignedCharValue];
        [payload appendBytes:&hex length:1];
    }
    [self sendCommand:GaiaCommand_SET_HEP_EQ_PSKEY
               vendor:CSR_GAIA_VENDOR_ID
                 data:payload];
}

- (void)getUserEQ {
    [self sendCommand:GaiaCommand_GetUserEQControl
               vendor:CSR_GAIA_VENDOR_ID
                 data:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is the implementation. Show the interface of `CSRGaia`. It begins with `@interface OSRGaia` and usually is in a header. (A file with the suffix .h.)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling this method:

'getUserEQ:'

notice the 2 dots colon

it's different from method

'getUser'

with no colon

and in your .m file there is only

```
- (void)getUserEQ {}
```

i guess you wanted to use the setter method, instead

```
- (void)setEQValues:(NSArray *)values{}
```

like this:

```
[[CSRGaia sharedInstance] setEQValues: values];
```

add anyway both

```
- (void)getUserEQ;
- (void)setEQValues:(NSArray *)values;
```

in CSRGaia.h file

between

```
@interface OSRGaia
```

and

```
@end
```